# ios-simulator doesn't work under ios 7

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, simulator

My ios-simulator works fine if i launch ios 7 on it, but if i try to launch ios 6 or 6.1 it just displays a black screen (i even don't start any app on it). I have tried to delete folder of ios-version and reinstall it, but nothing seams to work. May be i have to reinstall the whole simulator? If so, how that could be done? 
Here is what i find in console log:

```
 Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Reset Content and Settings..." menu item under the iOS Simulator menu before launching your 6.x target

[image]

Comment: Not helping. Thanks any way.